# DevOps pipelines read for public

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops, public

What recently happened to Azure pipelines in public projects that are not accessible to the public without login anymore? I believe it was fine a few weeks ago...

I was checking all configurations/options and searching forums/docs, but nothing useful.

UPDATE: https://x.com/AzureDevOps/status/1714979822907138218?s=20

Comment: [This is my public project/repo on Azure DevOps](https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_git/DevOps%20Manual) Could you access it?

Comment: it is public - https://dev.azure.com/Lightning-AI/lightning strange now it seems to be accessible :/

Comment: I can see your pipelines in this project.

Comment: We could not yesterday and tried it from multiple sources

Answer (score 0):

The public DevOps organization/project is **still accessible**.

Check the [status](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) page, not such issue reported.

If you are not able to, it's mostly caused by:

1. The public organization/project is **removed/renamed**, it could return `404` error when you access it.
2. They are changed from public to **Private** and you don't have access to, it could report `401`, `403` error when you check the network trace(F12).
3. The website could be blocked by firewall, change your network for a try.
4. If it reports `503` error on network trace(F12) when you access it, it's service error, you can report it on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) and wait, as you can doing nothing.

Comment: I do not have a problem with the project, but the pipelines associated with the project

Comment: Which pipeline in the project (dev.azure.com/Lightning-AI/lightning) you cannot access? And what would you like to check on the pipeline? I can still access the pipelines without login. It's recommended to share a screenshot.

Comment: yes, seems to work today but it was not the case past two weeks

Comment: Glad to know it's working now! It could be a temporary issue, but if it happens again, you can follow my comment list to have a check. Please post a simple reply and [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to the process as it doesn't occur now. Thanks.